# How to remove empty label from choices in django filters while using foreignkey

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPbgj.png)

This is the image.How to remove these (---------) lines from these choices.I am using django-filters.

The models I have created

```
class Notes(models.Model):
subjects = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
term = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SEMESTER_CHOICES, default=None)
download = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.subjects


class NotesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    subjects = CharFilter(field_name='subjects', lookup_expr="icontains", label='Subject', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Subject'}))
    term = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=SEMESTER_CHOICES, required=False, label='Semester', empty_label=None,widget=Select(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Subject'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Notes
        
        fields = ['subjects', 'faculty', 'program','term']
```

Comment: I am not using modelform instead of it am using django-filters

Comment: I think you are obliged to have the empty label if `required=False`. So make `term` obrigatory if that is the case. Doesn't make much sense for something to not be required, but you can't leave it empty.

Answer (score 2):

Those select options are called empty labels.

With django-filters you can set [`FILTERS_EMPTY_CHOICE_LABEL`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/settings.html?highlight=FILTERS_EMPTY_CHOICE_LABEL#filters-empty-choice-label) in your settings.py to change the default empty label for all choice filters from `'---------'` to a different string (e.g. an empty string `''`, or `'Please select an option...'`), or set to `None` to disable it.

You can also set the `empty_label` argument on individual [`ChoiceFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=empty_label#choicefilter)'s or [`ModelChoiceFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=empty_label#modelchoicefilter)'s. You have already done this for the `term` field.

You will need to define the `ForeignKey` fields manually as you have done for the other fields if you want to customise this on a per-field basis (without doing something more complex like extending the `__init__()` method), for example:

```py
class NotesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
   ...
   faculty = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Faculty.objects.all(), empty_label='Your empty label')
   ...
```

Comment: It is working for term but how can I use it with foregin key fields.In foreign key there are no CHOICES.

Comment: There are absolutely choices for ForeignKey form fields. They are [generated automatically by Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/59552bea5790c97be0da0a6f16ccd0189857c7a7/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L863) and `ModelChoiceField`'s [use `Select` widgets by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) which *require* `choices`.

Comment: Check my edited answer for specifics on how you might modify each field individually (if that's what you actually want here).